# How to get the azure account tenant Id?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My question is: Is it possible to get the azure active directory tenant id without using powershell command?

I found this two blogs and with this help, I'm already able to get the tenant ID and subscriptions ID from powershell.  Is it the only way to retrieve the tenant?

[Get Windows Azure Active Directory Tenant ID in Windows PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/31/get-windows-azure-active-directory-tenant-id-in-windows-powershell.aspx)

[Windows Azure AD authentication support for PowerShell](http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/windows-azure-ad-authentication-support-for-powershell/)

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in another programming language or are you asking for a non programming response? If the former you need to be more specific. If the ladder you are asking in the wrong forum

Comment: Found this web site that does the job : https://www.whatismytenantid.com

Comment: That feeling when 150K+ people got screwed by MS not being able to clearly communicate tenantId

Answer (score 274):

Time changes everything. I was looking to do the same recently and came up with this:

## Note

*added 02/17/2021*

[Stable Portal Page](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties) *thanks [Palec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157640/palec)*

*added 12/18/2017*

As indicated by shadowbq, the DirectoryId and TenantId both equate to the GUID representing the ActiveDirectory Tenant. Depending on context, either term may be used by Microsoft documentation and products, which can be confusing.

## Assumptions

- You have access to the Azure Portal

## Solution

The tenant ID is tied to ActiveDirectoy in Azure

- Navigate to Dashboard
- Navigate to ActiveDirectory
- Navigate to Manage / Properties
- Copy the "Directory ID"

Azure ActiveDirectory Tenant ID:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the profit part, but the rest worked for me! ☺

Comment: The "Tenant ID" **IS** the "Directory ID".

Comment: Microsoft sure like to keep people on their toes by naming everything 3 times.

Comment: What does "Navigate to ActiveDirectory" mean?

Comment: @thang: ActiveDirectory is pinned to the Azure portal by default, if you don't see it you can get there by entering "Azure Active Directory" in the search bar at the top of the portal and selecting the "Azure Active Directory" entry under "Services"

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But why not have only one name? Tanent Id or Directory Id???
Or have both at azure ad properties...

Comment: It seems the address of this screen is fairly stable: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties

Answer (score 116):

Go to https://login.windows.net/YOURDIRECTORYNAME.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration and you'll see a bunch of URLs containing your tenant ID.

Comment: Those ids are the subscription ids - not the tenant ids. When an account has multiple subscriptions, there are multiple directories and the tenantId equates to the directoryId at outlined in the answer by @KevinR below

Comment: You can have multiple subscriptions associated with a single tenant/directory.  Using the method above will show you the tenant ID, not subscription ID(s).  You can confirm by comparing the GUID from this method with the Directory ID in the portal - they will be the same.

Comment: super helpful in case you don't have access to the active directory blade

Comment: FYI: you can convert a subscription Id to a tenant Id by navigating to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION-ID?api-version=2014-04-01 (hover to see full URL) -- and inspecting the "WWW-Authenticate" header that comes back (you'll get a 401, but that header contains a URL with the tenant Id in it). :-)

Comment: In azure URL's (like the portal) you can typically use the YOURDIRECTORYNAME.onmicrosoft.com and tenant ID interchangeably - so if you know the directoryname, you can reference the tenant.

Comment: openid-configuration url does not work from code, gives 400

Answer (score 72):

My team really got sick of trying to find the **tenant ID** for our O365 and Azure projects. The devs, the support team, the sales team, everyone needs it at some point and never remembers how to do it.

So we've built this small site in the same vein as whatismyip.com. Hope you find it useful!

[**How to find my Microsoft 365, Azure or SharePoint Online tenant ID?**](https://www.whatismytenantid.com)

Comment: Brilliant. Why Microsoft makes an effectively public ID so difficult to find is beyond me.

Answer (score 63):

In the Azure CLI (I use GNU/Linux):

```
$ azure login  # add "-e AzureChinaCloud" if you're using Azure China
```

This will ask you to login via https://aka.ms/devicelogin or https://aka.ms/deviceloginchina

```
$ azure account show
info:    Executing command account show
data:    Name                        : BizSpark Plus
data:    ID                          : aZZZZZZZ-YYYY-HHHH-GGGG-abcdef569123
data:    State                       : Enabled
data:    Tenant ID                   : 0XXXXXXX-YYYY-HHHH-GGGG-123456789123
data:    Is Default                  : true
data:    Environment                 : AzureCloud
data:    Has Certificate             : No
data:    Has Access Token            : Yes
data:    User name                   : nico@XXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com
data:    
info:    account show command OK
```

or simply:

```
azure account show --json | jq -r '.[0].tenantId'
```

or the new az:

```
az account show --subscription a... | jq -r '.tenantId'
az account list | jq -r '.[].tenantId'
```

I hope it helps

Comment: actually, it's the azure cli..  but +1 for any cli.

Comment: This will also work with the new ```az``` CLI, thanks!

Answer (score 40):

The tenant id is also present in the management console URL when you browse to the given Active Directory instance, e.g.,

```
https://manage.windowsazure.com/<morestuffhere>/ActiveDirectoryExtension/Directory/BD848865-BE84-4134-91C6-B415927B3AB1
```

[image: Azure Mgmt Console Active Directory]

Comment: @Mjh, I hear you.  I'm surprised you're the first person to comment on my klugey suggestion.  Maybe it's obvious to the rest of the world that one would pull the tenant id from a uri.

Comment: Not obvious to me. I expected it to be shown in the UI somewhere. Having to hunt for it in the Uri or use powershell to get it after you authenticate is really weird. We want to limit certain tennants in our app so we need to ask for the ID from the tennant owner. This method is going to confuse a lot of them.

Comment: Not only is it madness, it's official =/ "The tenant id for your Office 365 tenant is displayed as part of the URL" see:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-your-Office-365-tenant-ID-6891b561-a52d-4ade-9f39-b492285e2c9b

Answer (score 36):

Just to add a new method to an old (but still relevant question). 
In the  new portal, clicking the help icon from any screen and selecting '**Show Diagnostics**' will show you a JSON document containing all your tenant information including TenantId, Tenant Name, and much, much more useful information

[image]

Answer (score 22):

This answer was provided on Microsoft's website, last updated on 3/21/2018:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

In short, here are the screenshots from the walkthrough:

1. Select Azure Active Directory.

[image: Azure Active Directory]

2. To get the tenant ID, select Properties for your Azure AD tenant.

[image: Select Properties]

3. Copy the Directory ID. This value is your tenant ID.

[image: Copy the Directory ID, this is the tenant ID.]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 17):

Via PowerShell anonymously:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest https://login.windows.net/YOURDIRECTORYNAME.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration|ConvertFrom-Json).token_endpoint.Split('/')[3]
```

Comment: He was looking for a way to do it without using the built-in commands -- fortunately, this demonstrates how to do it in any language... nifty.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to get it from App registrations

`Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations` -> click the app and it will show the `tenant ID` like this

[image]

Comment: I see no tenant ID under most items in azure.

Answer (score 9):

You can run a simple curl call to get the tenant id of an azure subscription without any authentication.

make a curl call to :

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}?api-version=2015-01-01`

The request fails but you will be able to get the tenant id from the response header. The tenant id is present in line followed by "WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/"

you can use `curl -v`  to show the response header.

Answer (score 6):

As of now (06/07/2018), an easy approach would be running **az account show** in the **Azure Cloud Shell** (requires a Storage Account) in the **Azure Portal**.

**--- Command ---**

```
az account show
```

**--- Command Output ---**

```
{
  "environmentName": "AzureCloud",
  "id": "{Subscription Id (GUID)}",
  "isDefault": true,
  "name": "{Subscription Name}",
  "state": "Enabled",
  "tenantId": "{Tenant Id (GUID)}",
  "user": {
    "cloudShellID": true,
    "name": "{User email}",
    "type": "user"
  }
}
```

Find more details on Azure Cloud Shell at [Overview of Azure Cloud Shell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

Comment: You can add the --query tenantId parameter to get the tenant Id exactly:

az account show --query tenantId

Answer (score 6):

If you have installed Azure CLI 2.0 in your machine, you should be able to get the list of subscription that you belong to with the following command,

```
az login
```

if you want to see as a table output you could just use

```
az account get-access-token --query tenant --output tsv
```

or you could use the Rest API

[Tenants - List | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Azure CLI

```
az account get-access-token --query tenant --output tsv
```

Comment: This is exactly what the questioneer is not asking for

Comment: This isn't a Powershell command - it's an Azure CLI command.

Comment: azure cli is far better and cloud native

Answer (score 4):

One click answer:

open this URL:

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell:

```
Add-AzureRmAccount #if not already logged in 
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName <SubscriptionName> | Select-Object -Property TenantId
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Login to [Microsoft Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)

Step 2: Search Azure Active directory

Step 3: Click on overview and find the tenant id from tenant information section

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have Azure CLI setup, you can run the command below,

```
az account list
```

or find it at `~/.azure/credentials`

Answer (score 1):

From Java:

```
public static String GetSubscriptionTenantId (String subscriptionId) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    String tenantId = null;
    String url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "?api-version=2016-01-01";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (Header header : headers)
    {
        if (header.getName().equals("WWW-Authenticate"))
        {
            // split by '"' to get the URL, split the URL by '/' to get the ID
            tenantId = header.getValue().split("\"")[1].split("/")[3];
        }
    }

    return tenantId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft:

**Find your tenantID:** Your tenantId can be discovered by opening the following metadata.xml document: https://login.microsoft.com/GraphDir1.onmicrosoft.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml - replace "graphDir1.onMicrosoft.com", with your tenant's domain value (any domain that is owned by the tenant will work). The tenantId is a guid, that is part of the sts URL, returned in the first xml node's sts url ("EntityDescriptor"): e.g. "https://sts.windows.net/".

Reference:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/

Comment: Two of the three are bad links.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get the tenantID is:

```
Connect-MsolService -cred $LiveCred  #sign in to tenant

(Get-MSOLCompanyInformation).objectid.guid  #get tenantID
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Azure Portal:**

- Step1: Login to azure portal and search for Azure Active Directory and select it .
- Step2: In the overview page of Azure Active Directory,find the tenant ID.

[image]

**Using Azure CLI:**

Use one of the commands az login, az account list, or az account tenant list. Find the TenantId property for each of subscriptions in the output from each command.

**Using Powershell**

Use the below command in powershell cmdlet.

```
Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzTenant
```

***Reference:***

[Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)

[Get-Aztenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-aztenant?view=azps-6.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

I use following to get tenant id

```
az account show --query homeTenantId --output tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of contributors already mentioned going to Azure Portal, opening the Active Directory page, and finding it there. However, some folks work for organizations that don't allow them to view the Active Directory page.

Another way to quickly find the Tenant Id in Azure Portal is to click on your account icon in the upper right corner of the Azure Portal

[image: Azure Portal account icon]

Select "Switch Directories" from the Account drop-down

[image: Switch Directories page]

You'll see a table with one or more Directories listed and showing their "Directory Id". Directory Id is the same thing as Tenant Id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the tenant id, in fact all subscription details by logging into the url resources.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

For AAD-B2C it is fairly simple. From Azure Portal with a B2C directory associated, go to your B2C directory (I added the "Azure AD B2C" to my portal's left menu). In the B2C directory click on "User flows (policies) directory menu item. In the policies pane click on one of your policies you previously added to select it. It should open a pane for the policy. Click "Properties". In the next pane is a section, "Token compatibility settings" which has a property "Issuer". Your AAD-B2C tenant GUID is contained in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The one working for me is this (after `az login`):

```
 az account show |grep tenantId | awk {'print $2'} |tr -d '[:punct:]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Azure portal > Azure Active Direcrory.
On the main screen, you should see your tenant ID.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
xxx@Azure:~$ az ad sp create-for-rbac
Retrying role assignment creation: 1/36
{
  "appId": "401143c2-95ef-4792-9900-23e07f7801e7",
  "displayName": "azure-cli-2018-07-10-20-31-57",
  "name": "http://azure-cli-2018-07-10-20-31-57",
  "password": "a0471d14-9300-4177-ab08-5c45adb3476b",
  "tenant": "e569f29e-b008-4cea-b6f0-48fa8532d64a"
}
```

Comment: It'll create a new **sp**.