# Polybase over Data Lake - what is the OAuth_2.0_Token_EndPoint?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, polybase

I'm trying to connect my Azure SQL Data Warehouse to my Datalake, [following the microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-data-lake-store).

Microsoft give the following code sample, but do not clarify what the OAuth_2.0_Token_EndPoint is and where to find it in the Azure portal.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ADLCredential
WITH
IDENTITY = '<client_id>@<OAuth_2.0_Token_EndPoint>',
SECRET = '<key>'
```

How do I work out what this should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-authenticate-using-active-directory#step-4-get-the-oauth-20-token-endpoint-only-for-java-based-applications

In the portal, go to AAD, click App registrations, then click Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from @BenV's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26386318/3932615)

> Go to
>   https://login.windows.net/YOURDIRECTORYNAME.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
>   and you'll see a bunch of URLs containing your tenant ID.

Once you are at that link, look for the entry for "token_endpoint". Copy and paste this value into the code posted above.