# Where to get required information to access Azure ServiceBus via API, especially ClientID and ClientSecret

Tags: c#, azure

I was trying to achieve the following scenario:

- Create a service bus queue via the API.
- Send a message to that queue.

Using C#.
If it was in AWS, I would need a couple of lines of code, and I need 3 pieces of information which are very easy to get, but it doesn't seem to be the case in Azure...

The pieces of information I realized that I need so far:
ClientId

ClientSecret

ServiceBusConnectionString

ServiceBusNamespace

QueueName

ResourceGroupName

TenantId [How to get the azure account tenant Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384034/how-to-get-the-azure-account-tenant-id)

SubscriptionId

After hours of research, I was able to collect everything apart from the first two items, ClientId and ClientSecret, where I can get them?

**EDIT**
Which one is the client ID?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register your app in Azure AD to get your clientid & client secret.

Follow these [steps](https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/creating-application-client-id-client-secret-microsoft-azure-new-portal/) to register in AAD. Note down the key (client secret) as it will not appear again anywhere.

**Synopsis**:

1. Login @ [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/)
2. Search 'Azure Active Directory' on top bar & open
3. Go to 'App Registrations' & add your app
4. Get the client id (this is Application ID & NOT Object ID) & add key (this is client secret)

Comment: Which one is client id, there are a million different IDs :(

Comment: See the step 6 in first link

Comment: Don't you think that this is ridiculous from Microsoft? have you tried AWS? it is just consistent, they call things their names, I am really tired for 3 days trying to integrate with a simple service, with AWS, it has taken about half an hour from scratch.

Comment: I know, there's a lot to improve in MS side always.. :)

Comment: The funny thing is that I integrated with AWS SQS using C#, it was my very first time doing anything with message queues, it was super smooth, now after I learnt a lot of concepts, it is taking me that long to integrate with Microsoft's own Queue service, anyway.

Comment: Just to complete the joke, the link you provided is wrong, the Client ID is actually the Application ID and not the Object ID as mentioned, it worked finally.