# Where is the secret key stored when you add authentication at project creation time in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

Assume I create an ASP.NET Core 2.0 App in Visual Studio 2017:

[image: ASP.NET Core project creation dialog]

I can integrate with Azure Active Directory by clicking the **Change Authentication** dialog.

[image: Cloud single orgationation auth dialog]

Then after entering my MSDN credentials 2 or three times it will register my application with Azure Active Directory:

[image]

That creates the following snippet in appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "XXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXX",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

Tenant Id matches [what this question said it would](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41028320).  And ClientId matches Azure ID. However, I don't see where this Key, that Visual Studio created during the app provisions, is stored:

[image: Keys]

Where is that stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the template of Visual Studio does't save the secret when it create it on the Azure. If you want a secret for this app, you can delete the old one and create a new.

Please Note: Once you left that page, the secret was not able to see again.

Comment: So I can have a client without a secret? I know the application Id is hard to guess because its a GUID, but I'm not sure I understand the security implications.

Comment: Yes. The project uses the OpenID connect to acquire the **id_token**  by default. So it should work well unless you want to get the **access_token** to call other resource(code grant flow). More info about protocols please refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code).

Comment: After dealing with this for a few weeks, it makes better sense now.